# Why is my table being injected into the html multiple times with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Jquery to dynamically return a list of products, render this as HTML and then show it on the page, using `$(selector).html(html)`.. however I've noticed if I add products to my cart too quickly (which calls the method to render the cart again, it is injecting the html twice sometimes.

For example, below code is what renders the menu:

```
  html  = "          <table cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"270px\">\n";
  html += "            <tr>\n";
  html += "              <th>\n";
  html += "                <h1>\n";
  html += "                  Current Order ID: " + $("input[name=cart_id]").val() + "\n";
  html += "                </h1>\n";
  html += "              </th>\n";
  html += "            </tr>\n";
  html += "            <tr id=\"cart_products\">\n";
  html += "            </tr>\n";

  return $.ajax({
    url: getAjaxUrl("cart/get_product"),
    data: args,
    type: 'get',
    global : false,
    success: function(data) { 
      if ( data.success ) {
        //cart is empty    
        if ( data.data == "" ) { 
          html += "              <td>\n";                                
          html += "                Your Cart is currently empty!\n\n";
          html += "              </td>\n";
        } else if ( ("data" in data) ) {  
          html += "              <td class=\"product\">\n\n";       
          html += "              <table cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">\n\n";       
          html += "                <tr>\n";       
          html += "                  <th>\n";       
          html += "                    Product\n\n";       
          html += "                  </th>\n";       
          html += "                  <th>\n";       
          html += "                    Qty\n\n";       
          html += "                  </th>\n";          
          html += "                  <th>\n";       
          html += "                    Action\n\n";       
          html += "                  </th>\n";        
          html += "                </tr>\n";      

          //loop over all products in cart
          $.each(data.data, function(i, product){
            if ( i % 2 != 0 ) {
              row_class = " alt";   
            } else {
              row_class = "";
            }
            if ( ! product.ok ) {
              row_class = " err";
            }

          //check if error            
            html += "                <tr>\n";            
            html += "                  <td class=\"dsc" + row_class + "\">\n";                        
            html += "                    <em>" + product.code + "</em><br />\n";                        
            html += "                    " + product.description;                         
            if ( product.whqc != "" )                                                        
              html += "                    <br />WHQC: <strong>" + product.whqc + "</strong>\n";  
            else
              html += "                    \n";  
            html += "                  </td>\n";                        
            html += "                  <td class=\"qty + " + row_class + "\">\n";                        
            html += "                    <input id=\"qty_" + product.id + "\" name=\"qty\" type=\"text\" value=\"" + product.qty + "\" class=\"qty\" maxlength=\"5\" size=\"5\" />\n";                         
            html += "                  </td>\n";                        
            html += "                  <td align=\"center\" class=\"action" + row_class + "\">\n";                                                    
            html += "                    <img style=\"cursor:pointer; cursor:hand\" data-product_id=\"" + product.id + "\" id=\"cart_product_update\" src=\"" + getImageUrl() + "cart_product_update.png\" />\n";
            html += "                    <img style=\"cursor:pointer; cursor:hand\" data-product_id=\"" + product.id + "\" id=\"cart_product_delete\" src=\"" + getImageUrl() + "cart_product_delete.png\" />\n";                        
            html += "                  </td>\n";             
            html += "                </tr>\n";                          

          });

          html += "              </table>\n";
          html += "              </td>\n";        
        }

        $("#cart_products").html(html);

      } else {
        alert("error");
      }                     
    }
  });
```

Starting at the line where it says `html += "<td class=\"product\">\n\n";` is sometimes pushed into the html twice.

Any idea why that is and how to stop it? I thought using `html` method was safe as it doesn't append- it replaces, however it seems that the method is stepping on its own toes. I know I could do something with boolean values like `isLoading = true`, however I'd like to avoid that.

[image][image]

Comment: Perhaps you should reset the `html` variable the first time, instead of appending to it: `html = "<td>\n";`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include that bit in my post as didn't think it was needed. See my update where I am doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should initialize your html variable properly:

```
var html = '';
```